# Perl parsing Text File with regular expression

Tags: perl

I have a file with the following random structures:

```
USMS 1362224754632|<REQ MSISDN="00966590832186" CONTRACT="580" SUBSCRIPTION="AAA" FORMAT="ascii" TEXT="L2"
```

or

```
USMS 1362224754632|<REQ MSISDN="00966590832186" CONTRACT="580" SUBSCRIPTION="BBB" THRESHOLDID="1" FORMAT="ascii" TEXT="L2"
```

I am trying to parse it with perl to get the values like the following:

1362224754632;00966590832186;580;AAA;L2

Below is the code:

```
if($Record =~ /USMS (.*?)|<REQ MSISDN="(.*?)" CONTRACT="(.*?)" SUBSCRIPTION="(.*?)" FORMAT="(.*?)" THRESHOLDID="(.*?)" TEXT="(.*?)"/)
{
                              print LOGFILE "$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7\n";
}
elsif($Record =~ /USMS (.*?)|<REQ MSISDN="(.*?)" CONTRACT="(.*?)" SUBSCRIPTION="(.*?)" FORMAT="(.*?)" TEXT="(.*?)"/)
{
                              print LOGFILE "$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6\n";
}
```

But I am getting always:

```
;;;;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe (`|`) is a special character in regular expressions. Escape it, like: `\|` and it will work.

```
if($Record =~ /USMS (.*?)\|<REQ MSISDN="(.*?)" CONTRACT="(.*?)" SUBSCRIPTION="(.*?)" FORMAT="(.*?)" THRESHOLDID="(.*?)" TEXT="(.*?)"/)
```

and the same for the `else` branch.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a single regex, I would split the data into its separate sections first, then approach them separately.

```
my($usms_part, $request) = split / \s* \|<REQ \s* /x, $Record;

my($usms_id) = $usms_part =~ /^USMS (\d+)$/;

my %request;
while( $request =~ /(\w+)="(.*?)"/g ) {
    $request{$1} = $2;
}
```

Rather than having to hard code all the possible key/value pairs, and their possible orderings, you can parse them generically in one piece of code.

Comment: @Schwern - I up'd your answer. If any of keys are changed in the data file, the original regular expressions will fail - this includes: order of keys, spelling of the keys, and the key counts. Far better to have a more open (or general-purpose?) capturing of the key/value pairs, to account for future changes. And storing in an indexed hash, good add. Though I would have used some form of 'record-number' for the first level key: '$request{$rnum}{$1} = $2;'

Comment: I would follow that approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
(.*?)
```

to

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

Comment: This would give him `1362224754632;;;;;` instead of just `;;;;;`, but wouldn't fix the unescaped pipe problem. It's still good advice in general, though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you want is the fields contained in double-quotes.

That looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @values = /"([^"]+)"/g;
  print join(';', @values), "\n";
}

__DATA__
USMS 1362224754632|<REQ MSISDN="00966590832186" CONTRACT="580" SUBSCRIPTION="AAA" FORMAT="ascii" TEXT="L2"
USMS 1362224754632|<REQ MSISDN="00966590832186" CONTRACT="580" SUBSCRIPTION="BBB" THRESHOLDID="1" FORMAT="ascii" TEXT="L2"
```

**output**

```
00966590832186;580;AAA;ascii;L2
00966590832186;580;BBB;1;ascii;L2
```